# How to iterate list of list with two element in jstl

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, jstl

```
Class PatientOverall{

    private Patient objPatient;

    private List<PatientHistory> objPatientHistory;


//getters and setters

}
```

// Controller

```
class Controller{

List <PatientOverall> objTestDetails = new ArrayList<>();

modelandview.addObject("Test",objTestDetails);

}
```

// ObjTestDetails has **3** list details.

Now How to iterate the list in JSP using JSTL.

Help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${Test.list1}">
${test1. objPatient}
  <c:forEach var="innerlist" items="${list. objPatientHistory}">

  ${innerlist}

  </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```